# Websocket client not receiving data

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, binary

I have a weird issue. After reading about websocket-client, it seems easy enough, send data via `websocket.send()` and receive via `recv()`.

I have setup my websocket to read and send a binary file. The codes are below

```py
ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect(uri)

text_list = list()

# setup the receiving portion
receiving_tread = threading.Thread(target=thread_receiving, args=(ws, text_list))
receiving_tread.start()

ws.send_binary([48])  # telling server file has started

f = open(binary_file, 'rb')

chunk = f.read(8000)

while chunk != b'':
    ws.send(chunk)

    time.sleep(0.5)
    chunk = f.read(8000)

ws.send_binary([49]) # tell server file has ended
```

The process to receive the data:

```py
def thread_receiving(ws, text_list):
    data = json.loads(ws.recv())
    text_list.append(data)
```

I know the data gets sent because I get the first part of the data returned, then it stops. So I get only 1 return and somehow the `recv()` stops listening. Note: I have no access to the server or the server websocket so I have to troubleshoot from the client side.

Can anyone tell me, what it is I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found the answer, it seems that the receiving function exits after it runs. So we need to keep it running.

Therefore,

```py
def thread_receiving(ws, text_list):
    data = json.loads(ws.recv())

    while len(data) > 0
        text_list.append(data)
        data = json.loads(ws.recv())
```